# How to get a specific value using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get only the numbers in the brackets like this, having the following string:

`itsonlyaexample[0:4:2]test`

I need to extract only `0` , `4` , `2`

OR

`itsonlyaexample[0]test`

I need to extract only `0`

How to do this with `C#`?

I've tried this, but not get only the numbers in brackets:

`(\[[0-9]{1}\]|\[[0-9]{1}:[0-9]{1}\])`

Comment: Can there be two digit numbers like "itsonlyaexample[10:20]"?

Comment: If you are looking for colon separated numbers inside of square brackets then you should be able to do this with `string` functions instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "itsonlyaexample[0:4:2]test";
var result = str
    .Split('[')[1]
    .Split(']')[0]
    .Split(':')
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var takeBrackets = str
    .SkipWhile(x => x != '[')
    .Skip(1)
    .TakeWhile(x => x != ']');

var result = string.Concat(takeBrackets).Split(':');
```

Comment: I liked your previous answer better, this would return numbers outside of the brackets.

Comment: @juharr fair enough. I haven't thought about that.

Comment: +1 The other thing that sets this apart from the other answers is that it handles 2 digit numbers.  Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: MY answer would also deals with two digit number.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it doesn't in the demo link you added.

Comment: it works only for this example. What if the input is `9foo89)[bar90mny)[foo67nar90kk9]` ?

Comment: I'm going to test this

Comment: @AvinashRaj this example I don't need, I need only numbers within the brackets and splitted by ":"

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind please clarify your question. So that we don't end with these type of confusions.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind my updated regex would work for `[5:6:7:8:8:9]` type of input also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this kind of pattern with a global research:

```
@"(?:\G(?!\A):|\[)([0-9]+)(?=:|(]))"
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5cG(%3f!%5cA)%3a%7c%5c%5b)(%5b0-9%5d%2b)(%3f%3d%3a%7c(%5d))&i=itsonlyaexample%5b0%3a4%3a2%5dtest)

The pattern use the `\G` anchor that matches the position after the previous match result. So with this anchor, you can find consecutive elements in a string.

The lookahead with a capture group inside at the end is only here to check if the closing square bracket is reached. (if the second capture group contains `]`, it's good).

The main interest of this approach is that it can deal with an undetermined number of items. An other advantage with the final lookahead is that you can check the format by testing the existence of the second capture group.

Note: if you are looking for these number in a large amount of datas, you can try to improve your pattern with the *first character discrimination technic*  by adding a lookahead at the begining to *skip* all the character until the opening square bracket (or a semicolon):

```
@"(?=[\[:])(?:\G(?!\A):|\[)([0-9]+)(?=:|(]))"
```

This will avoid to test the two branch of the alternation for each characters before a possible opening square bracket.

**pattern details**:

```
(?:             # the two possible entry points:
    \G(?!\A):      # after a previous match, so followed by a semicolon 
  |               # OR
    \[             # an opening square bracket  
)
([0-9]+)        # capture the number
(?=             # lookahead to test if you have reached the end
    :
  |
    (])
)
```

This way can be used in several languages like .net, perl, java, php, ruby...

**an other approach for .net**

But you can use a .net particularity that allows to store the different results of a repeated capturing group:

```
string input = @"itsonlyaexample[0:4:2]test";
string pattern = @"\[(?:([0-9]+):?)+]";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success) {
   foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures) {
       Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input contains balanced parenthesis then you could use a positive lookahead assertion to match all the numbers which are inside the parenthesis.

```
@"\b\d\b(?=[^\[\]]*\])"
```

**OR**

```
@"\b\d+\b(?=[^\[\]]*\])"
```

The above regex matches the number only if it's followed by any character but not of `[` or `]` zero or more times and after that there must be a closing `]` parenthesis. `(?=[^\[\]]*\])` is a positive lookahead assertion which won't consume any characters but it's the one which decides where the match to be occur.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oL0oQ9/1)

**Code:**

```
String input = "itsonlyaexample[0:4:2]test\nitsonlyaexample[0]test";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\b\d\b(?=[^\[\]]*\])");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ByStZl)

**Explanation:**

```
\b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
\d                       digits (0-9)
\b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  [^\[\]]*                 any character except: '\[', '\]' (0 or
                           more times)
  \]                       ']'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

**Update:**

```
(?:\[|(?<!^)\G)\D*(\d+)\b(?=[^\[\]]*\])
```

Get the numbers within parenthesis from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oL0oQ9/2)

Comment: added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks! so, if my test is witha  parenthesis is also finding the numbers like: itsonlyaexample2`(`3:4:4:2:4]test . How to find the numbers ONLY if is in brackets? [ and ]

Comment: your comment is not clear. could you add the input within backticks?

Comment: Your demo will match the 0 in "itsonlyaexample(0]" when it shouldn't, also doesn't match 2 digits number (but I'm not sure if that matters)

Comment: I need to get the numbers ONLY within the brackets "[" and "]" but, if starts with parenthesis too found the numbers, like this: (2:3:4], so, if starts with parenthesis I DON'T NEED the numbers.

Comment: OK, I guess I was confused by the requirements.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you understand me?